# make local repo equal to Github repo

Tags: git, github, terminal, repository

I did make some changes in Github (added some lines and changed a file name), but now my local repo is different from the Github repo.

I would expect that `git status` would show which files are different, and then `git add .`+ `git commit -m '*'`+`git push` would make my Github repo the same as my local repo, but it doesn't... How can I fix this?

Comment: Did you also push the Changs to the repo?

Comment: yes I did, but it didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The git command does not fetch new data from the origin everytime you run it. You will have to first `git fetch --all`, in order to get all new changes from the origin or if you don't have uncommitted changes or you have not made commits locally that are not already on GitHub you are able to just do `git pull`.

Comment: I tried, but when I try `git commit -m '*'` I get the message: 'On branch main
Your branch and 'origin/main' have diverged,
and have 1 and 2 different commits each, respectively.
  (use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)

nothing to commit, working tree clean
' and when I use git pull after that I get the message: 'hint: You have divergent branches and need to specify how to reconcile them.
***(a lot more in the middle)***
fatal: Need to specify how to reconcile divergent branches.' I am quite new to github/git...

Comment: First of all you are trying to do a commit with the commit message "*". That error message is telling you, that GitHub is having changes your local repository has not and vise versa. Try `git pull` and if that gives you an error you can either stash your local changes with `git stash` and apply them after pulling from GitHub with `git stash apply` or you can try to `git rebase origin/main`, but if you get a rebase conflict you will have to resolve it locally and continue by `git rebase --continue`. You could also try `git pull --ff-only`.

Comment: So just to clarify. Your problem is, that you edited files in your local copy and tried to commit them. Your GitHub Repo on the other hand had changes you made through the website. Correct?

Comment: I tried `git pull`+`git rebase origin/main`+`git rebase --continue`. After that I was able to use `git add` etc., but my github repo still isn't the same as my local repo (it added a `procfile` to github (without capital letter)

Comment: What did `git rebase origin/main` output? You started a rebase process, which if a conflict occurs all changes that are different between your local and your remote branch are getting written in your file which in turn mostly will result in errors in code. You need to resolve these conflicts and then use `git rebase --continue`. You are using `git add .` to add changes to a commit. The `.` in that command stands for the current directory you are in with your terminal.

Comment: `git rebase` = `CONFLICT (modify/delete): procfile deleted in HEAD and modified in 4250c9f (changed).  Version 4250c9f (changed) of procfile left in tree.
error: could not apply 4250c9f... changed
hint: Resolve all conflicts manually, mark them as resolved with
hint: "git add/rm <conflicted_files>", then run "git rebase --continue".
hint: You can instead skip this commit: run "git rebase --skip".
hint: To abort and get back to the state before "git rebase", run "git rebase --abort".
Could not apply 4250c9f... changed`

Comment: You had a conflict. This means in your files there are now all differences between GitHub and your local machine. Use `git rebase --abort` to abort this process. You are not able to use other git commands until you have either resolved these conflicts or aborted the process. On your machine how much changes did you do and tried to commit?

Comment: I changed 1 word in Procfile and changed the name of a file

Comment: Then please do the following:
`git rebase --abort` + `git fetch --all`+ `git reset --hard origin/main`. NOTE: This will erase the local changes from your machine and then will get the current state of GitHub. Then you can redo all the changes you did manually again. Is that okay for you?

Comment: ok, I did that. What should I do now?

Comment: I edited the comment. Please read the NOTE below first, before you do these commands.

Comment: Ok, so only that repo I was working on will be changed?

Comment: Yes these git commands are only referring to the repo you are currently working in. You can just in case, you are not fine with the changes, locally copy that directory just as a backup

Comment: Ok, I did it. It returned `HEAD is now at 1e64afc *`

Comment: Okay. Now you can go ahead and change files on your local machine, commit and push them.

Comment: I did everything you told me, but my Github repo is still different...

Comment: Okay. That is weird. What do you mean by different? You push your changes and they don't appear on the website?

Comment: in Github i have a `Procfile` and a `procfile`, in my local repo I only have the `Procfile`

Comment: I guess you renamed the procfile? How did you do that? Locally or via the website? Did you edit your `.gitignore?`

Comment: I don not have a `.gitignore` and i did rename `procfile` to `Procfile` (via giithub)

Comment: Using `git pull` does not help?

Comment: `git pull` returns `Already up to date.`

Comment: That is extremely weird. Normally you would have both files. You could try to clone the repo in another folder again and look if the files are there. If that's not the case, I can't tell you what happened with that renaming process. If that's the case I am sorry.

Comment: Minor side note: the `--all` flag to `git fetch` means *all remotes* and hence only does anything if you have more than the usual single `origin` remote.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
git checkout main
git commit -m "<your-commit-messages>"
git push -f
```

It will overwrite your Github repo with your local changes.